# React Dropzone with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use [React Dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) in my form built with React Hook Form, but I can't catch the file on form submission.
I've tried with [Controller](https://react-hook-form.com/api#Controller), but not works (works fine without dropzone).

```js
<S.Dropzone isDragAccept={isDragAccept} {...getRootProps()}>
  <p>Drag 'n' drop file here, or click to select file</p>
  <input type="file" name="file" ref={register} {...getInputProps()} />
</S.Dropzone>
```

Full code in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-with-react-dropzone-d4o2m?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js)

If someone could help me to see what is wrong, I appreciate.

Comment: have you tried with custom register? useEffect(() => register('input') }) and use setValue to set the input value.

Comment: It's work! Thank you!

Comment: @jflizandro Are you able to focus the dropzone on validation error. Could you share your code please.